# Excel Copy Paste only works correctly in protected view

Tags: excel, excel-2010

In a project I am currently working on I copy data from one file to another and then have a bunch of lookups and condition working with the copied data.

For some reason this copy only works correctly when in protected view and using the paste special: Keep Destination formatting.

If I have an unprotected file where I copy values only from I have the issue that I have to enter every cell and press enter so the formatting is correct and my lookup functions work.

Comment: Is calculation turned to manual? In which case turn it to auto, and they should recalculate.

Comment: no it is not. The weirdest thing is that when the worksheet is protected copy paste works fine but when its not I get this issue..